# Set zookeeper host and port for spring-cloud-bus

Tags: java, spring, apache-zookeeper, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-bus

I have a project with spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka and I set the kafka URL inside `application.yml` like so:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
```

This works find when kafka and zookeeper are deployed locally, but if I move kafka and zookeeper to their own servers I get an error when spring-boot starts:

**New config**

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=192.168.0.120:9092
```

**Error**

```
{
    "@timestamp" : "2018-05-15T14:56:45.628+00:00",
    "message" : "Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)",
    "logger_name" : "org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn",
    "thread_name" : "main-SendThread(localhost:2181)",
    "level" : "INFO"
}
{
    "@timestamp" : "2018-05-15T14:56:45.629+00:00",
    "message" : "Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect",
    "logger_name" : "org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn",
    "thread_name" : "main-SendThread(localhost:2181)",
    "level" : "WARN",
    "stack_trace" : "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)"
}
```

How I should config kafka and zookeeper to connect to their servers?

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? With 2.0, no connection to zookeeper is required.

With earlier versions, you need to set `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes`.

[Spring Cloud Stream documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR3/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_kafka_binder_properties).

Comment: I'm using `1.5.10.RELEASE` and also tried `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=192.168.0.120:9092` but didn't work

Comment: No; you need port 2181 (by default) for ZK - 9092 is the kafka broker.

Comment: Didn't work either, still trying to connect to localhost:

    {
        "@timestamp" : "2018-05-15T16:09:07.898+00:00",
        "message" : "Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@653b9612",
        "logger_name" : "org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper",
        "thread_name" : "main",
        "level" : "INFO"
    }

Comment: I just tested it by adding a bogus zkNodes value - pointing to a server that doesn't have ZK running, and got your error; you must have configured it incorrectly.

Comment: Not sure what else I'm doing wrong if I telnet 192.168.0.120:2181 I get connected, this is what i have in my application.yml file:

`spring.cloud.bus.trace.enabled=true`
`spring.cloud.bus.ack.enabled=false`
`spring.cloud.bus.refresh.enabled=false`
`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.zkNodes=192.168.0.120`
`spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=192.168.0.120:9092`

Comment: I've also tried with and without this `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=192.168.0.120:9092` while have the zkNodes configured and didn't work.

Comment: `spring.cloud.stream.kafka..zkNodes=192.168.0.120` should be `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes`.

Comment: yes, sorry about that was a typo when I've pasted the config here, but yeah, that is what I have: `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes`

Comment: Well, I just copied yours and added `binder` `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=192.168.0.120` and I get `Opening socket connection to server 192.168.0.120/192.168.0.120:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)`, followed by `Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 10006ms for sessionid 0x0`. So there's something else you are doing incorrectly - are you sure that properties file is the one being used?

Comment: Thank you @Gary Russell, I'm using a config-server and it was down, so I restarted and now the app it's taking the proper config

Answer (score 0):

There's a section on Spring's documentation about it:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR3/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_kafka_binder_properties

You can replace the default URL on `Application.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          zkNodes: ADDRESS:PORT
          brokers: ADDRESS:PORT
```

Or using `.properties`

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes = ADDRESS:PORT
```